# AspDot Net Storefront 9.x Add class for each category to the body

Tags: aspdotnetstorefront

I need to add the name of each category to the body class. I have searched for a way to dump the variable for the category name inside of the template.master file with no luck. I can get the page name or meta info but not the category name.

So it would be 
    `<body class="mycategory">`

My styling on the whole page (even outside of the entity.category.xml.config) will be affected by this class.

Update: So an example structure on the site would be Clothing > Men > Brand 1 > product 1. I want a a class that shows up for the whole clothing section regardless if I am on a a product, sub category, or sub-sub category.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this in your master file:

```
<body class='body <aspdnsf:XmlPackage runat="server" PackageName="bodyclass" />'>
```

Then create an xml package named bodyclass.xml.config. In that file add this:

```
<xsl:if test="/root/Runtime/EntityName and /root/Runtime/EntityID">
    <xsl:text> e-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/Runtime/EntityName" />
    <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="/root/Runtime/EntityID" />
</xsl:if>
```

This will create classes like e-category-53 rather than category name, but they will give you the same flexibility. They will also work for other entity types like sections and manufacturers.

Another useful one here is:

```
<xsl:text> url-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="translate(aspdnsf:StrReplace(/root/Runtime/PageName, '.aspx', ''), '.', '')" />
```

This will generate a body class based on the url like 'url-c-88-sename'. This will apply to ALL pages, not just entity pages.

Comment: At first I was getting an error so I changed the body tag to be `<body class='body <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Tokens:XmlPackage, bodyclass.xml.config %>" />'>`

Comment: Now it is including the file, but not returning the category. If I add static text it comes back just fine in the body class, but the if statement is coming back as false and if I remove it nothing returns. Any ideas?

Comment: Also the select page example you gave works just fine and is returning as expected, but nothing for the entity name or id. Thanks for your help!

Comment: try taking the if off and tell me what you get. The node names have changed a bit through all the 9 versions.

Comment: I still get nothing, it seems weird though because I am on a category. The page one returns the page just fine

Comment: So if I just select Runtime - `<xsl:value-of select="/root/Runtime" />`. I get the foloowing en-USFalse0en-USFalseUSD1en-USbodyclass.xml.configFalseFalseTruehttps://domain.com/5/8/20151/c-236-accessories.aspxfalseFalseen-USFalse129.123.28.23615False03:08 PM1USD0en-USc-236-accessories.aspxFalseFalse. Accessories.aspx changes to the product name when I click on a product in the category. Everything I read makes me think the entity should be there though

Comment: copy-of will show you the full nodes (you'll have to view source). you should also try turning on debug - the results will help troubleshoot. You said the page based one was working - shouldn't that cover all the same use cases?

Comment: So an example structure on the site would be Clothing > Men > Brand 1 > product 1. I want a a class that shows up for the whole clothing section. When I get the page title it only works on clothing itself but won't work on sub categories or products. To add classes for each product would be crazy and hard to update. When I do copy-of entity name isn't available as a node. I tried writing my own queries and got it to work for a sub category or top category but not for product or a sub-sub category

Comment: Oh - I'd misunderstood and thought you meant on the specific category page - that's where EntityType and EntityID show up in the XML document.

Comment: I think the solution is going to be more complicated than you're going to get here. You'll need to account differently for category and product pages. For product pages you'll need a custom query to get all mapped categories (and make sure you consider multiple mappings). Then you'll need to traverse up the EntityHelper tree to add a class for parent categories.

Comment: Gotcha, I was hoping I could get the entity from runtime or another global variable. I haven't worked with aspdotnetstorefront before, most ecommerce software I have used have a category variable available or the category stays in the URL. I wasn't sure if I was just missing something. It is outputting the parent in the breadcrumbs, but the breadcrumbs seems to be a system wide functionality, I can't find the xml file for that. I appreciate your help though